# ¿Como hacer que cuando pones un numero te diga si esta repetido en una select de mysql?

Tags: python, mysql

Hola lo que quiero conseguir es que cuando yo ponga el codigo del jugador, si pongo un codigo de jugador que ya esta en la base de datos me lo diga y me vuelva a preguntar otro codigo de jugador (un bucle)

```
s1ql="SELECT codigo FROM jugadores"
    codigo=input("Codigo del jugador: ")
    if codigo in s1ql:
        print(f"el codigo {codigo} ya esta en uso")
```

Comment: Tu código está perfecto (mas allá de que hay (en mi opinion) mejores formas de saber si algo existe en la base de datos), lo unico que te falta es el bucle while. Hay algún problema que no estoy captando? Por que razón sabiendo bien que necesitas no lo has hecho hasta ahora?

Comment: No esta bien porque no me hace el print

Comment: Perdón, miré mal el código. Encontré el fallo. Cuando tenga más tiempo (si es que nadie responde antes) daré una respuesta.

Comment: Okey muchas gracias!

Comment: A mi parecer, te hace falta el `WHERE` en tu consulta, por decir `SELECT * FROM [nombre de la tabla] WHERE [la columna de tu tabla]  = [codigo]` o en tu caso `SELECT codigo FROM jugadores WHERE codigo = [codigo]` y ya lo que menciona el anterior comentario, el bucle WHILE para que al hacer la consulta te despliegue al final "EXISTE" y vuelva a preguntarte por otro código

Answer (score 2):

#### Explicación

Tu código ni siquiera consulta a la base de datos. Si prestas atención, la variable `s1ql` hace referencia a una cadena (que es una consulta sql valida, pero que en tu código nunca se ejecuta).

Cuando se ejecuta el condicional `if codigo in s1ql:` lo que realmente hace es buscar el código ingresado por el usuario en la cadena s1ql. En pocas palabras, si el usuario ingresa por ejemplo "1000", esta linea se vuelve equivalente a `"1000" in "SELECT codigo FROM jugadores"`. Por supuesto, esto da Falso y por lo tanto no imprime.

#### Código de ejemplo (sin probar)

Nota: este código está sin probar. Si hay algún fallo, por favor avisame para que lo arregle.

```
import mysql.connector

# Inicio una conexión a la base de datos. Esta linea la saqué de un tutorial.
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                     database='Electronics',
                                     user='pynative',
                                     password='pynative@#29')

# Inicio un cursor, esto nos permitirá consultar y modificar la base de datos.
cursor = connection.cursor()

# ejecutamos una consulta que nos devuelva los códigos de todos los jugadores
cursor.execute("SELECT codigo FROM jugadores")

#guardamos el resultado de la consulta en la variable codigos. Usamos cursor.fetchall para obtener todos los registros de la consulta.
# esto devuelve algo del estilo [(codigo1,), (codigo2,), (codigo3,), ...] 
# donde cada item de la lista es una fila de la base de datos
codigos = cursor.fetchall()

# esta lista contendrá los códigos en el estilo [codigo1, codigo2, codigo3, ...]
codigos2 = []

# por cada código ejecutamos la linea de abajo
for codigo in codigos:
    # agrego el primer item de la fila código a codigos2
    codigos2.append(codigo[0])

while True:
    codigo = input("ingrese un código: ")

    # busco si el código ingresado está en la lista de códigos
    # si el código está...
    if(codigo in codigos2):
        print("el código no está disponible")
    else:
        #rompo el bucle infinito
        break
```

Me basé en lo que supuse que querías hacer para escribir este código. Este enfoque tiene algunas desventajas. Las cuales enumeraré:

#### Desventajas del enfoque original

Estas contras son insignificantes si la base de datos es pequeña, pero si hablamos de millones de registros, es mejor tener esto en cuenta.

- Cargas todos los códigos en memoria. Esto para bases de datos grandes consume mucha memoria. Ya que la estás llenando con códigos.
- El cliente es el que determina si el código está disponible, no el servidor sql. Además de la menor velocidad que puede implicar si la computadora del cliente es lenta, Python en si es un lenguaje más lento que mysql. Por lo que a Python le lleva más tiempo encontrar un item en una lista que a mysql un registro en una tabla.

#### Un enfoque que utiliza el poder de MySql para mayor velocidad y menos gasto de memoria (podría no funcionar)

Yo no uso MySql, sino que se más sobre Postgresql y Sqlite3, por lo que esta consulta podría fallar.

Cada vez que quieras saber si un código está disponible, puedes ejecutar el siguiente fragmento de código basado en [un tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table#:%7E:text=To%20test%20whether%20a%20row,false%20is%20represented%20as%200.):

El modelo de la consulta es:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM yourTableName WHERE yourCondition)
```

Y el fragmento sería:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT codigo FROM jugadores WHERE codigo=%s)", (codigo,))
# Obtenemos un solo registro, esto viene en formato (True o False,)
# Obtenemos el primer item de esa tupla, que será un booleano indicando si hay al menos un registro cumpliendo la condición o no.
existe = cursor.fetchone()[0]

if(existe):
   ...
```

Comment: Hola, el codigo que has puesto tu no me funciona porque no me salta el print del bucle cuando esta repetido el codigo

Comment: @juanperez Es decir, que imprime incluso si el código no está disponible? La columna código es numerica?

Comment: Si es INT la columna

Comment: La función input SIEMPRE devuelve una cadena. No se como funciona MySql, Postgresql te transforma la columna de cadena a entero automáticamente. Pero quizá en este motor haya que hacer una conversión explicita. Prueba a ver que pasa si conviertes la cadena devuelta con input en entero usando la función int y cuentame si funcionó.

Comment: Si estás usando la primera forma que propuse (la cual insisto de no usar) es seguro que tendrás que convertir el código a numero.

Comment: okey gracias ahora te digo.

Comment: No consigo hacerlo he modificado algunas cosas del codigo que me propusiste y no me funciona gracias

Comment: De nada. Que modificaciones hiciste? Cual de los dos códigos propuestos estás usando?

Comment: el primero `        s1ql="select codigo from jugadores"
        mycursor.execute(s1ql)


        codigos = mycursor.fetchall()    
        codigos2 = []

        for codigo in codigos:
            codigos2.append(codigo[0])

        while True:
            codigo = input("ingrese un código: ")

            if(codigo in codigos2):
                print("el código no está disponible")
            else:
                break      
`

Comment: Seguro que probaste en hacer lo que te dije de convertir el contenido de la variable código a numero con la función int? Por que en el código que pasaste no lo haces.

Comment: si lo probe pero me dio un error al instante

Comment: Cual error te dió?

Comment: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ingrese un código: '

Comment: no me deja ni insertar un numero

Comment: Cambiaste la función input por int. A lo que me refería era algo como int(input("ingrese un código"))

Comment: Funcionooo!!!!!!! muchas gracias amigoo!!!

Comment: De nada compañero c: