# Validación de usuario al registrarse en python

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.7

Estoy tratando de hacer que el usuario cuando ingrese un nombre de usuario que ya existe en la base de datos, le tire un mensaje de error diciendo que ese usuario ya existe. Desconozco el metodo para poder realizarlo. Yo estuve probando de esta manera, si pueden ayudarme se lo agradeceria. Adjunto el código.

```
def registrarte(self):

    usuario = self.usuario.get()
    nombre_apell = self.nombre_apell.get()
    clave = self.clave.get()
    dni = self.dni.get()
    correo = self.correo.get()
    fecha = datetime.datetime.now()

    # conexión
    db = sqlite3.connect('PDVdamoonplay.db')
    conexion = db.cursor()

    # verificación 
    query = conexion.execute('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?', [usuario])
    if query == usuario:
        messagebox.showerror(title = 'ERROR', message = 'El usuario ingresado ya existe en el sistema, por favor ingrese otro!')
    else:
        if usuario != '' and nombre_apell != '' and clave != '' and dni != '' and correo != '' :
            conexion.execute('INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,5)',(usuario, nombre_apell, clave, dni, correo, fecha))
            conexion.close()
            db.commit()
            self.usuario.set('')
            self.nombre_apell.set('')
            self.clave.set('')
            self.dni.set('')
            self.correo.set('')
            self.ventana_registro.destroy()
            self.carga_login()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror(title = 'ERROR', message = 'Para continuar, necesita completar el registro!')
```

Comment: Esto responde a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/520435/158880. Es en MySql, pero sabiendo que hay muchos estandares, podría funcionarte.

Comment: Veo si me funciona y te aviso, muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya pude resolverla, muchas gracias!

Comment: Genial que lo resolviste y gracias por aportar con una respuesta! Para ayudar mejor a aquellos que tengan tu misma duda más adelante podrías agregar una explicación de lo que hace tu respuesta :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basicamente, primero declaro las variables que se van a usar en las querys, luego se verifica en los entry que no haya ningún caracter dentro, y si es asi el sistema sigue, se hace una conexión a la base de datos y se realiza la primera query para establecer si en la base de datos se encuentra otro usuario con el mismo nombre de usuario, luego con el fetchone(), contatas el valor que traes con la query y recién ahí se realiza el INSERT a la base de datos del registro, sl final se ciera la base de datos para que no genere problemas.

```
def registrarte(self):

    usuario = self.usuario.get()
    nombre_apell = self.nombre_apell.get()
    clave = self.clave.get()
    dni = self.dni.get()
    correo = self.correo.get()
    fecha = datetime.datetime.now()

    # conexión
    if usuario != '' and nombre_apell != '' and clave != '' and dni != '' and correo != '' :
        pass
    # esta correcto
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(title = 'ERROR', message = 'Para continuar, necesita completar el registro!')
        return

    db = sqlite3.connect('PDVdamoonplay.db')
    conexion = db.cursor()

    # verificación 
    conexion.execute('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?', [usuario])

    if conexion.fetchone():
        messagebox.showerror(title = 'ERROR', message = 'El usuario ingresado ya existe en el sistema, por favor ingrese otro!')
    else:
        conexion.execute('INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,5)',(usuario, nombre_apell, clave, dni, correo, fecha))
        db.commit()
        self.usuario.set('')
        self.nombre_apell.set('')
        self.clave.set('')
        self.dni.set('')
        self.correo.set('')
        self.ventana_registro.destroy()
        self.carga_login()

    # Conexión cerrada
    conexion.close()
    db.close()
```

Comment: ¿Alguna explicación?

Comment: Hola Dani, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de ayuda a la persona que pregunta o a usuarios futuros que puedan encontrarse un problema similar. Por favor, edita la respuesta para añadir una breve descripción de lo que hace el código que compartes y cómo soluciona el problema. Lee [answer] para más información.